# Dialer Apps crash after a few seconds, 4.4, almost new phone, no modifications

Tags: applications, crashes

As titled. Two week old Sony Z3 Compact, running 4.4. Not flashed/rooted. Plenty of apps installed. I'm very new to Android, so I have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this issue, and could use some advice. It's a new phone and I can't make calls. I'd like to avoid the wipe everything and start again approach I've seen elsewhere online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you can, try to go to `Settings -> Applications -> All
   applications` and find your Dialer app (usually called dialer). Then
   delete data and reboot your phone. That should fix issues coming
   directly from the dialer app itself.
2. If other applications like
   `Contacts` or `Messages (Hangouts)` crash then some databases inside
   your phone (eg. contacts.db) are corrupt or have wrong permissions
   associated with them.

Rooting and then fixing permissions **manually** may solve the problem if the first option didn't do it.

Comment: I don't have dialer in the list - could it be called something else?

Comment: For me it's called "Telephone". Maybe you find that in your list.